# YouTube API showing 102 queries being made per request

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

So this is sort of weird. For every 1 request sent from my website using our YouTube API key, the developer console shows 102 queries actually being made. Here is the query format (using Python) -

```
search_q = '<query-string-here>'
service = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey='<api-key>')
results = service.search().list(
     part='snippet', 
     channelId='<specific-channel-id-to-search-through>',
     type='video',
     q=search_q,
 ).execute()
```

My logs show only one request being sent using this but my query count on the quotas page increases by 102.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug on Google's end?

Comment: Youtube follows points system, your one query costs 102 points, I guess that's what is happening here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) to approximate the quota costs your request is using. Sure enough the search API request quota is on 100 range:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that each request cost a different amount of points. Thanks for clarifying and sharing that info with me!